# If dentro de Campo PHP

Tags: php, html, if, envio-de-email, echo

Boa Tarde,

Como Fazer um if dentro de atribuição de valor de variavél.

```
$html ='
          <body>
          <table width="100%" style="background:#00aeef;">
          <tr><td>
          <table width="596" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family:Arial;background:#FFF;">
            <tr>
              <td height="78" colspan="2"><img name="index_r1_c1" src="email/img/index_r1_c1.png" width="595" height="78" id="index_r1_c1" alt="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td height="200" colspan="2" valign="top" style="font-size:16px;padding:30px 15px;font-family:Arial;"><h3>Olá,</h3>
             <h3>     O Cliente abaixo se interessou por um de seus itens publicados no jornal, seguem os dados dele:</h3> 
             <strong>Nome</strong>: '.$nome.'<br>'.
             if($email != ""){
                <strong>E-Mail</strong>: '.$email.'<br>;
                }

             if($whatsapp != ""){
                <strong>WhatsApp</strong>: '.$whatsapp.'<br>;
                }.'
             <h3>Segue abaixo informações sobre o imóvel:</h3>
```

No caso $html esta montando o corpo de um e-mail e gostaria que aparecesse apenas o campo ($email, $whatsapp) caso o mesmo seja diferente de vazio.

Comment: Faça o IF separado, dentro de outras variáveis, e coloque apenas o resultado.

Comment: O mais simples é não fazer isso. Você pode concatenar o valor desejado com a variável dentro do `if`, mas se quiser, pode utilizar o operador ternário.

Answer (score 1):

O mais simples é concatenar os valores dentro das condições desejadas:

```
$email = "foo@bar.com";
$whatsapp = "";

$html = "<h1>Aqui começa seu HTML</h1>";

if ($email != "") {
    $html .= "<strong>E-mail: {$email}</strong>";
}

if ($whatsapp != "") {
    $html .= "<strong>WhatsApp: {$whatsapp}</strong>";
}

echo $html;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/6Bz96L).

A saída seria:

```
<h1>Aqui começa seu HTML</h1>
<strong>E-mail: foo@bar.com</strong>
```

Embora você pode utilizar o operador ternário, mas isso dificulta bastante a leitura do código:

```
$email = "foo@bar.com";
$whatsapp = "";

$html = "<h1>Aqui começa seu HTML</h1>" .
        (($email != "") ? "<strong>E-mail: {$email}</strong>" : "") .
        (($whatsapp != "") ? "<strong>WhatsApp: {$whatsapp}</strong>" : "");

echo $html;
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/SRINks).

A saída seria exatamente a mesma:

```
<h1>Aqui começa seu HTML</h1>
<strong>E-mail: foo@bar.com</strong>
```